# Different output on emulator and test device for the same android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have developed an app which receives following steps:

1. PACKAGE_ADDED
2. PACKAGE_REMOVED
3. PACKAGE_REPLACED
4. PACKAGE_CHANGED

If I run this app in an emulator everything works fine.

But if I run the same code I am unable to receive the step

1. PACKAGAE_CHANGED
2. PACKAGE_REPLACED (I get PACKAGE_REMOVED and PACKAGE_ADDED instead)

From what I had read PACKAGE_REMOVED intent could only be received by system apps.
But now I am able to receive it as a user app also.
Any idea how is this possible and why is there a difference in output?

Comment: Which android version is running on the emulator and on the device?